# FCM Chrome extension: This method is available in a service worker context. (messaging/only-available-in-sw)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've been trying to integrate FCM with a chrome extension I am making. 
In my service worker file(firebase-messaginng-sw.js), I am getting the following error:

> FirebaseError: Messaging: This method is available in a service worker
>   context. (messaging/only-available-in-sw).

Below are the relevant code snippets.

**manifest.json**

```
"permissions": ["tabs", "storage", "notifications"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["./lib/firebase/firebase-app.js",
                "./lib/firebase/firebase-auth.js",
                "./lib/firebase/firebase-messaging.js",
                "./background.js"
              ]
  },
```

**background.js**

```
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.usePublicVapidKey("XXXXXX");

const currentToken = await messaging.getToken();

console.log(`Current token ${currentToken}`);

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    await navigator.serviceWorker.register('./firebase-messaginng-sw.js');
    initialiseState();

  } else {
    console.warn('Service workers aren\'t supported in this browser.');
  }
```

**firebase-messaginng-sw.js**

```
firebase.initializeApp({
  'messagingSenderId': '111111111'
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
    console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
    const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
    const notificationOptions = {
      body: 'Background Message body.',
      icon: './public/icon.png'
    };

    return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
        notificationOptions);
  });
```

The whole integration part has been quite difficult for me as many resources online are deprecated or don't work for extensions. If you can also guide me towards any guide specifically for this, that would be amazing.

Comment: Try to remove `"./firebase-messaging-sw.js"` inside background scripts and try it again.

Comment: Didn't work. Now it's throwing Failed to update a ServiceWorker: ServiceWorker script evaluation failed

Comment: Dev Tools > Application > Service Workers. Did you see any error message in this panel?

Comment: Not seeing anything there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I've done to create a Chrome extension that receives notifications via Firebase and it's working for me. Some of this might be redundant or unnecessary or whatever. But it seems to work.

Note that I never call `firebase-messaging-sw.js` directly. Firebase apparently loads it itself.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "version": "1.1.7",
    "name": "Push Test",
    "permissions": [
        "notifications",
        "https://www.gstatic.com/",
        "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.1/firebase-app.js"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "This extension is just a push-notification tester.",
    "icons": {
        "16": "icon16.png",
        "48": "icon48.png",
        "128": "icon128.png"
    },
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.gstatic.com; object-src 'self'"
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Push Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
</head>
<body>
    <p id="pushLabel">This is just a test of push notifications via Firebase.</p>

    <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
    if (permission === 'granted')
    {
        console.log('Notification permission granted.');
        // TODO(developer): Retrieve an Instance ID token for use with FCM.
        // ...
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.');
    }
});

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
    /*
      What you should put here can be found inside
      https://console.firebase.google.com/
    */
};

console.log('firebase:');
console.log(firebase);

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
console.log('firebase initialized');

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
console.log('messaging created');
messaging.usePublicVapidKey("PutYourOwnKeyHere");
console.log('key defined');

setTimeout(function()
{
    console.log('timeout running');
    // Get Instance ID token. Initially this makes a network call, once retrieved
    // subsequent calls to getToken will return from cache.
    messaging.getToken().then((currentToken) => {
        console.log('getToken');
        if (currentToken)
        {
            console.log('getToken success');
            $('#pushLabel').text(currentToken);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('getToken failure');
            // Show permission request.
            $('#pushLabel').text('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('getToken error: ' + err);
    });

    // Callback fired if Instance ID token is updated.
    messaging.onTokenRefresh(() => {
        console.log('onTokenRefresh');
        messaging.getToken().then((refreshedToken) => {
            $('#pushLabel').text(currentToken);
        }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('onTokenRefresh error: ' + err);
        });
    });
}, 5000);
```

**firebase-messaging-sw.js**

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.1/firebase-auth.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.1/firebase-messaging.js');

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
    /*
      What you should put here can be found inside
      https://console.firebase.google.com/
    */
};

console.log('firebase:');
console.log(firebase);

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
console.log('firebase initialized');

// Retrieve Firebase Messaging object.
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```